# How do I write this in my batch script?

Tags: batch, cmd.exe, robocopy

The command is

```
robocopy M:\Tech_Supt\$Software\Open Way & Motion PC files and Config\OpenWay Install Objects\ C:\OpenWay Install Objects\ /e
```

The path is awful due to the spaces and & characters.
How can I write it so that it will copy to the `OpenWay Install Objects` folder to `C:`?

I can't change the path names.

Comment: Have you tried quotes?

Answer (score 2):

When you have space in path or filename, you have to use quote :
`robocopy "M:\Tech_Supt\$Software\Open Way & Motion PC files and Config\OpenWay Install Objects\" "C:\OpenWay Install Objects\" /e`